# SQL Server 2008 Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I cannot store the date data type variables using stored procedure.  My code is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Access1Register] 
 -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
 @MobileNumber int, 
 @CitizenName varchar(50),
 @Dob char(8),
 @VerificationCode int
AS
BEGIN
 -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
 -- interfering with SELECT statements.
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    select CAST(@dob As DATE)
 Insert Into Access1 (MobileNo,CitizenName,Dob,VerificationCode)
 values(@MobileNumber,@CitizenName,@Dob,@VerificationCode)
go
```

If I exec this procedure it is executing, but there is an error occured in the date type variable.  It's raising the error as `invalid item '-'`.

Comment: what **EXACTLY** is the error message?? And what kind of values are you passing in the `@Dob` parameter?

Comment: are you possibly running the DB in a lower compatibility mode?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how you pass in the `@Dob` values.

Your best bet is to use the ISO8601 format - 'YYYYMMDD' - since that will always convert to DATE properly - regardless of your language and regional settings on your SQL Server machine.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the date format that you pass.

If it is `'mm-dd-yy'` you can use `CONVERT(DATE, @Dob, 110)`, if it is 'dd-mm-yy' then `CONVERT(DATE, @Dob, 105)`.

Answer (score 0):

In which format you are passing the `@Dob` values? And what error you are getting exactly?

If you will pass the `@Dob` values in the format of `mm-dd-yy`, it should work correctly and no errors will be there.